# Python Decompose number function that recieves number and ways to decompose

Tags: python

I'm Trying to create a function that decomposes a number with just given numbers:

For example the number to decompose is 5 and the ways to decompose it are 1,2,5

```
def func(Number_to_decompose,list_with posible_ways_to_decompose)
func(5,[1,2,5])
```

so the function should return:

```
[[1,1,1,1,1],[2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1],[1,1,2,1],[1,1,1,2],[5]]
```

taking into account that numbers in the list are adding
so [1+1+1+2] is 5!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has quite a natural recursive fomulation:

```
from copy import copy
def recurse_find(decomposed,remaining,valid_numbers):
    #base case
    if remaining == 0:
        return decomposed
    #find all valid subtractions
    else:
        ans = []
        for number in valid_numbers:
            if remaining - number >= 0:
                new_decomposed = copy(decomposed)
                new_decomposed.append(number)
                cand = recurse_find(new_decomposed,remaining- 
                              number,valid_numbers)
                if cand:
                    ans.append(cand)
        if len(ans) > 0:
            return ans
```

print(recurse_find([],5,[1,2,5])) --> matches your requested output.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `itertools.product` for different repeats in a list comprehension then outside list comprehension for checking:

```
import itertools
def func(n,l):
   return [a for i in [itertools.product(l,repeat=x) for x in range(1,6)] for a in i if sum(a) == n]

print(func(5,[1,2,5]))
```

Output:

```
[(5,), (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

If wanted list of list:

```
print(list(map(list,func(5,[1,2,5]))))
```

Output:

```
[[5], [1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```